# Utility or library to send virtual keypress, incl modifiers and function keys on Wayland

Tags: keyboard, libraries, input, wayland

I want to make something akin to virtual keyboard, capable of sending virtual keypress of a full keyboard including the modifiers and function keys, but I have never done anything similar to this so I don't even know how the input stack works or how to start googling for this to begin with.

I have heard of `libinput`, but I don't understand how it would be related to what I want to do; is there anything like a ready-made text utility or something that can trigger a keypress?

**EDIT**

After a little more digging, I think what I am looking for is triggering `scancode` or `keycode`. Just need a decent generic library to do that.

Comment: Could you give an example of a possible use case?

Comment: @Pourko, basically an on-screen keyboard to click/tap on.

Comment: Oh, so you're talking about a full-blown graphical interface?  I am out of here.

Comment: @Pourko, I just need some library that can send keypress signals. Whatever you have on mind, please shoot.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `wtype`. It's similar to `xdotool` but for Wayland.

https://github.com/atx/wtype

It basically uses the Wayland client together with [virtual-keyboard](https://wayland.app/protocols/virtual-keyboard-unstable-v1) :

> Virtual keyboard
>
> The virtual keyboard provides an application with requests which
> emulate the behaviour of a physical keyboard.
>
> This interface can be used by clients on its own to provide raw input
> events, or it can accompany the input method protocol.

Note that this does not currently work on Gnome due to [this bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/1974)